# Can this shape contain a circle?

Tags: geometry, algorithms, circles, mobius-transformation

I have a shape, made up of interconnected squares. Their sizes are all equal and known. Think tetris blocks, but the shapes can be made of any number of squares, greater than or equal to one.

I need to know whether it is possible for this shape to contain ANY circle, that comes into contact, or encloses ALL the squares in the shape, and NO part of the circle is outside the shape. This includes the circle's interior as well as its circumference. A circle being tangent to a square does not count as being in contact with it.

For example:

- A 2x2 shape can fit a circle, with maximum diameter of 2 square units, therefore it is valid.
- A 3 square L shape can. It can fit a circle that lies tangent (internally) to the sides of the 'elbow' square and hits the opposite corner. Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1y1u.jpg
- A 3x1 shape cannot. The maximum size of the possible circle is 1 unit, and its not possible for the circle to be in contact with all three squares.

Things I do know so far:

- If the difference between the width and height of the shape is more than one square, it is not valid.
- If there is a hole in the shape, its not valid.

I need some kind of algorithm, as I will likely need to program this in Java.

I have been told that using the Möbius Transformation could potentially be useful, but the maths behind it is beyond my level.

Is this possible to do algorithmically, or by checking against a set of rules?

*(Sorry for no images, the image uploader does not seem to be working for me)*

Comment: Not sure I understand your criteria: When you say "a $3$-square L can" it sounds as if a circle in the "elbow" square touches all three squares in the sense you mean. But if that's right, then a circle in the middle of a $3 \times 1$ shape also touches all three squares, which appears contrary to your third bullet point. Could you please clarify? (If it matters, Möbius transformations have no bearing on this question unless I've completely misunderstood your intent.)

Comment: It may be necessary to define "touches" a bit more precisely. From your examples, it seems you mean that a circle "touches" a square if the circle contains a point in the square's interior. (or equivalently, if the intersection of the interiors of the two shapes is nonempty)

Comment: @Kajelad That seems to be the case.  For example, the circle with center $(5/8, 5/8)$ with radius $1/2$ contains an interior point of the unit squares with centers $(1/2, 1/2)$, $(3/2,1/2)$, and $(1/2, 3/2)$ without touching the unit square at $(3/2, 3/2)$.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Apologies for not being fully clear, I'll try and clarify with some examples: Take the "3-square L" you fit a circle that has diameter equal to the diagonal of the unit square, and fit it into the elbow of the shape. This circle will then come into contact with all three squares. Then take the 3x1 shape. The circle's diameter can only be as large as the width & height of the unit square, otherwise the circle will be outside the shape. 
So its not possible for any part of the circle to be in contact with all 3 squares. Being tangent to a square does not count as touching it.

Comment: But a circle whose diameter is the diagonal of the "elbow" square is _circumscribed_, so doesn't lie within the L...?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Oops, screwed that up, re-explain: The circle can be tangent (internally) to the outer sides of the elbow square, and also hit the opposite corner. The circle will then be in contact with all three squares. Sorry, this would've been easier to show if I can get these images to upload...

Comment: Ah, thank you! Something about the original wording had me mistakenly thinking circles were assumed to have unit diameter.

Answer (score 0):

For a given center $(x_0,y_0)$ and a given radius $r$, the condition for the included square centers is:
$$
(x_i-x_0)^2-(y_i-x_0)^2 \le r^2
$$

For example, for the center $(0,0)$ and radius $1$, the shape 2x2 is generated, and for radius $2$, the shape 4x4 is generated.

For the center $(0.5,0.5)$ and radius $1.5$, the shape 3x3 is generated and with radius $2$, the shape 4x4 without 1x1 corner squares is  generated.

As shown, the solution dependa on the center, which can be greatly standardized by taking the round of the mean for each coordinate:
$$
(x_0,y_0)=([\overline{x}],[\overline{y}])
$$

This will discard some "pathological" cases which arise by using the mean operator alone:

For the center $(0,0)$ and radius $2$, the shape 4x4 is generated, but, for the center $(0.25,0.25)$, the shape 4x4 includes one 2x1 top block and one 1x2 right block, with a total of 20 blocks, and with the given center as the exact mean of the coordinates. 
By applying the round operator we remove those 2x1 and 1x2 block by having the $(0,0)$ center